# Como evitar arquivo php ser executado quando estiver sendo processado?

Tags: php

Como é possível impedir que um arquivo em php quando ele esta sendo executado não seja executado por outro usuário?

um exemplo:

Usuário X abre o arquivo exe.php o tempo de processamento dele vai ser em 25 segundos neste tempo o usuario Y resolve abrir o arquivo exe.php mas ele não pode ser executado pois o usuario X ainda esta processando o arquivo.

Existe uma solução para isto?

Comment: Até tem uma série de maneiras diferentes para isso, como a resposta do colega @epx (que ja levou meu +1) mas a impressão que dá é que você está com um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/70), ou seja, perguntando do caminho que você acha que é a solução, em vez de expor o verdadeiro problema.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode tentar criar um arquivo temporário, se for Linux poderia ser algo como /tmp/exe.php.lock, e apagar quando o processamento termina. Mas há um grande risco de o arquivo não ser removido se o PHP falhar no meio do caminho.

Outra saída é criar um socket numa porta bem-definida e fixa. Se o bind() falhar é porque outra instância já criou o socket naquela porta e ainda não saiu. Você pode consultar o exemplo em http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php para ver como criar o socket; só precisa ir até o bind(), e não esquecer do socket_close() ao final.

e fechar o socket quando acaba o processamento. A chance do socket ficar aberto se o PHP falhar no meio do caminho é menor, ou talvez inexistente.

Comment: Sua resposta está melhor do que as da postagem original do fechamento (inclusive eu mencionei na original o problema do lock "órfão", que você sabiamente resolveu com o `bind()`). Pena que o pessoal do SOpt não faz _merge_ de postagens.